# saving qplot outside function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have a function that plots estimates and its 95% credible interval and calculates how many times the true value falls within the interval.

Using ggplot2, I plot the intervals, but I want to save it to pdf outside my function because I need to repeat this for multiple datasets.

Here's my function:

```
require("ggplot2")

CIbias <- function(truevalue, data, cilow, cihigh, PP){ 
  ppn = 1:PP 
limits <- aes(ymax = cihigh, ymin = cilow)

ciplot = qplot(ppn,data)+geom_errorbar(limits, width = 1)+geom_abline(intercept = truevalue,
 slope = 0) 

true = 0  
for(i in 1:PP){
  if(truevalue > cilow[i] & truevalue < cihigh[i]){
  true = true + 1
  } 
}
bias = (true / PP)*100
  return(list(ciplot, bias)) 
}
```

Here's an example of the function with the iris dataset:

```
data(iris)

CIbias(6, iris[,2], iris[,2 ] - sd(iris[,2]), iris[,2] + sd(iris[,2]), 150)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `pdf` function within `CIbias`, for example,

```
CIbias <- function(truevalue, data, cilow, cihigh, PP, fname){ 
    ....
    pdf(fname) 
    print(ciplot)
    dev.off()

    return(....)
}
```